# How to display values of $data in saveAction() before saving the action

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, extensions, forms, debugging

I've created an Adminhtml extension with a form and in the controller I have the saveAction(). I need to debug it and I need to see the values of $data, but `var_dump($data);` doesn't work, it just returns the success or error message.

This is the code that I have in my saveAction within the controller:

```
public function saveAction() {
        if ( $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
            $this->_getSession()->setFormData( $data );
            $model = Mage::getModel( 'namespace_module/table' );
            $id    = $this->getRequest()->getParam( 'entity_id' );

            try {
                if ( $id ) {
                    $model->load( $id );
                }
                // TODO: filter out attributes we don't want to allow changes to
                $model->addData( $data )->save();

                $this->_getSession()
                     ->addSuccess( $this->__( 'Result was successfully saved' ) );
                $this->_getSession()->unsFormData();

                if ( $this->getRequest()->getParam( 'back' ) ) {
                    $params = array( 'id' => $model->getId() );
                    $this->_redirect( '*/*/edit', $params );
                } else {
                    $this->_redirect( '*/*/list' );
                }
            } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError( $e->getMessage() );
                if ( $model->getId() ) {
                    $this->_redirect( '*/*/edit', array( 'id' => $model->getId() ) );
                } else {
                    $this->_redirect( '*/*/new' );
                }
            }

            return;
        }

        $this->_getSession()->addError( $this->__( 'No data found to save' ) );
        $this->_redirect( '*/*' );
    }
```

Could you guys help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hope you will find this helpful http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/debug

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't give me any indication about how to use it within a controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this line after `if ( $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {`

```
Mage::log($data, null, 'debug.log', true);
```

and the array will be logged in `var/log/debug.log`.
You are seeing the success message because the saveAction does not have an output. It just does a redirect to the edit page.

If you want you can use `var_dump($data)` but you need to stop the execution. add an `exit` after the `var_dump` statement.

Comment: how can I save data directly to the grid if am not getting that from API,